# Modify PHPBB Emails And Use HTML Themes

Tags: html, css, email, phpbb, phpbb3

I am using PHPBB 3.1.10 and have setup my forum to use Gmail to send emails and though slightly slow it works fine.

One thing i would like to do is modify all of the Emails i actually sends out by default for registration, lost passwords etc.

Right now it sends pure text emails like:

> Welcome to ForumName forums
>
> Please keep this email for your records. Your account information is
>   as follows:
>
> ---------------------------- Username: SomeUserName
>
> ### Board URL: http://forum.com
>
> Your password has been securely stored in our database and cannot be
>   retrieved. In the event that it is forgotten, you will be able to
>   reset it using the email address associated with your account.
>
> Thank you for registering.

It would be great if i could modify the text of these though and also wrap it in styled HTML and CSS so i can have a nice theme and include things like graphics and social media buttons to make it look more professional. How can i do this?

Also is there any way to automatically send extra emails than default so i can do things like Halloween and Christmas greetings etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and you need an extension. I know "SiteSplat" developed it about 3 years ago. Check the developer website and contact them via the contact forum or twitter: https://sitesplat.com/